# Error on RDLC Expression

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I am using this exp to calculate total fees paid on RDLC report:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!ResponseDescription.Value ="Approved Successful",Int(Fields!Amount.Value), 0))
```

And i get the `#ERROR` in the resulting column , what can be the issue ? .

And similar Exp above it work fine :

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!ResponseDescription.Value <> "",Int(Fields!Amount.Value), 0))
```

Few notes:

1- `Amount` is always `INTEGER` and present.

2- `ResponseDescription` is always a `STRING` and present.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
=Sum(CInt(IIf(Fields!ResponseDescription.Value ="Approved Successful", Fields!Amount.Value, 0)))
```

You have to convert every possible values to the same type before aggregation.

I think the second expression works fine because you are always in the `True` case (`Fields!ResponseDescription.Value <> ""`) so it always used an expression already converted to `Integer`.